# why is ubuntu 18.4 still showing as a linux subsystem when i have uninstalled it?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, subsystem

Why is ubuntu 18.4 still showing as a linux subsystem when I have uninstalled it?

How do I remove it?

Uninstalled through windows app store. But I did a manual install first so I think that may be the issue but an unsure how to rectify. Still new to this